# Why a generic method of an interface can be implemented as non-generic in Java?

Tags: java, generics, java-8, generic-constraints

Let's say we have a few test interfaces/classes like this:

```
abstract class Plant {
    public abstract String getName();
}

interface Eatable { }

class Apple extends Plant implements Eatable {
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Apple";
    }
}

class Rose extends Plant {
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Rose";
    }
}

interface Animal {
    <T extends Plant & Eatable> void eat(T plant);
}
```

You can see `Animal.eat` is a generic method with constraints. Now I have my `Human` class like this:

```
class Human implements Animal {
    @Override
    public void eat(Plant plant) {
    }
}
```

which compiles fine. You can see `Human.eat` is less constrained than `Animal.eat` because the `Eatable` interface is lost.

Q1: Why doesn't the compiler complain about this inconsistency?

Q2: If `Plant&Eatable` *downgrades* to `Plant` is acceptable for the compiler, why it complains on `eat(Object plant)`?

Comment: Which version of Java are you using. Using Java 1.8 in eclipse gives compile time error as expected.

Comment: @Codebender Java8 in Intellij IDEA.

Comment: @Codebender I have no issue compiling this. https://ideone.com/7xUcZn

Comment: @ElliottFrisch But it happens in compile phase, the compiler knows that, and I think it should gives an error, at least a warning?

Comment: That's exacly what @ElliottFrisch just said.

Comment: Just tried it with `javac` on the command line, and it doesn't get an error.  But if I change `Plant` to `Rose` in the parameter list of `Human.eat`, I now get an error.

Comment: For what it's worth, I can't think of a case where the posted code causes a "problem"--i.e. where code compiles, but at runtime the code attempts to call an `Eatable` method on an object of a class that doesn't implement `Eatable` (assuming we added some methods to `Eatable`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Lesson: Generics by Gilad Bracha](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/convert.html)
 according to him

> ```
> public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<T> coll)
> ```
>
> > This is an example of giving multiple bounds for a type parameter,
> >     using the syntax T1 & T2 ... & Tn. A type variable with multiple
> >     bounds is known to be a subtype of all of the types listed in the
> >     bound. When a multiple bound is used, the first type mentioned in the
> >     bound is used as the erasure of the type variable.

so your example `<T extends Plant & Eatable> void eat(T plant);` will be erased to `void eat(Plant plant);` so when you override it the compiler doesn't complain

Answer (score 0):

Ahmed answer is right,by the way,if you wanna put constraint the implementation of the interface of Animal, you should declare it as this:

```
interface Animal<T extends Plant & Eatable>  {
    void eat(T plant);
}
```

Then, if you implements the Animal interface without providing the type information, the compiler will using the least surprise policy to infer the T as a Plant type. But if you provide the necessary type information, the compiler works fine.

```
class Human implements Animal<Rose> // won't compile
class Human implements Animal<Apple> // compile
```